# ReactJS fetch data not display

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to fetch a list of users from AWS using redux. On my localhost everything works fine, but when i put the app on a server, i don't see the users on page, i only see them on console. If i try to refresh the page, i get 404 error. Can someone explain me what's happening? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

In my component i do this first

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  await this.props.GET_USERS()
}
```

Here is my action

```
export const GET_USERS = () => async dispatch => {
  var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'POOL_ID'
  }

  try {
    const response = await new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider().listUsers(params).promise()
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS', response: response.Users })
  } catch(err) {
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS_ERROR', response: err })
  }
}
```

Here is my reducer

```
const usersReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, users: action.response }
    case 'GET_USERS_ERROR':
      return { ...state, users: action }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And here is the code where i display the users

```
{
  this.props.users ? 
    this.props.users.length ?
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            this.props.users.map(el => (
              <tr key={ el.Attributes.find(attr => attr.Name === 'sub').Value }>
                <td>{ el.Attributes.find(attr => attr.Name === 'email').Value }</td>
                <td>{ el.Attributes.find(attr => attr.Name === 'given_name').Value }</td>
                <td>{ moment(el.UserCreateDate.toString()).format('MMMM Do YYYY hh:mm a') }</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    :
      <p className="empty">No users found!</p>
  :
    <div className="loader"></div>
}
```

Comment: Did you connect props from redux to the component?

Comment: Of course, on localhost everything works fine...

Comment: I solved this by myself. I added return keyword here this.props.users.map(el => { return (....)})